# Don't want the images to get out side a defined div size; Image resolution should be maintained; Don't mind if the image is cut

Tags: css, html, image

I am trying to create an album preview in HTML by showcasing thumbnails; All the thumbnails should be defined square in shape.

Now, when I am trying to show the thumbnails, either the resolution of some images is distorted, else in the other case(i.e.) if I don't set both the properties(height and width), the images come out of the DIV and overlaps other images.

Can you please tell, how to achieve to show the image without loosing image resolution such that they don't come out of the div; I don't mind if the image is cropped.

A simple solution is good as I am using tables and I don't want to use iFrames for this.
Thanks!!

Comment: Try to resize them based on width and height you want - check http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php or https://github.com/adeelejaz/jquery-image-resize/tags

Comment: Are you providing true thumbnails or are you trying to ask the browser to scale down the full sized image?  If you're just scaling down the full sized image, that's not very good for the users...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `overflow: hidden` on your div

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
     <img src="images/thumb-01.png"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail{
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your each images has own div parent then you can use css overflow on div. remove height and width from images.

```
div{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kar8J/). Set same width and height to all images

If the images resolutions differ alot with each other then use `div`'s instead of `img` and give images as background to them.

In this situation you can use

```
overflow:hidden;
background-size: 100px 100px; /* CSS3 */
```

Using [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) you can set the images dimensions as you need.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by the following method

HTML Code

```
<div class="kq"><div class="img_div"><img src = "sample.jpg" /></div></div>
```

CSS Code

```
.kq{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
padding: 8px 12px 12px;
position: relative;
width : 60%;
margin : 0 auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
overflow: hidden;
```

}